# How to override ListViewItem style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm trying to override the ListViewItem style using this code:

```
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                         Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />

        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

unfortunately seems that `MaterialDesignListViewItem` isn't included in the `MaterialDesignInXaml` so I got the `StaticResource` underlined for not found.

My goal is change the color of selection when the mouse is over an item.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: What about using an `EventTrigger` instead?

Comment: You don’t need to base the style on anything. Just omit BasedOn.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few things going on here.

In MDIX there are two styles that are used for ListViews. The grouped style, `MaterialDesignGridViewItem` and the normal `MaterialDesignListBoxItem`. To override either of these styles you will need to manually bring in the appropriate resource dictionary (`MaterialDesignTheme.ListView.xaml` and `MaterialDesignTheme.ListBox.xaml` respectively).

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ListBox.xaml" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                     Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```