# How to style ListViewItem with ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, controltemplate

I'm new to WPF, and this whole world of binding and styling is pretty confusing.

I have created a copy of default ControlTemplate for ListViewItem:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        ...
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then I have columns in my ListView, for example:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstFiles">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="clmName" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If I add new item in Designer, I can easily apply that ControlTemplate:

```
<ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem1" Template="{DynamicResource ListViewItemControlTemplate1}"/>
```

But how do I use that template when items are binded to ListView from code using `lstFiles.ItemsSource`?

Comment: The template will be applied regardless of how you set the ItemsSource property. What exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to override the style for your listviewitem. from: [How to override ListViewItem style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035365/how-to-override-listviewitem-style)

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ListBox.xaml" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                 Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
</Style>
```